# Acccessing Pandas series data

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python Pandas and I am calculating the RSI Indicator via Python Pandas. I am getting an index series from type float64.

```
0 100
2 200
```

I just need always the last value e.g. 200 but don't know how to get this. I tried to access it via index but no chance

```
def get_rsi(series, period):
    delta = series.diff().dropna()
    u = delta * 0
    d = u.copy()
    u[delta > 0] = delta[delta > 0]
    d[delta < 0] = -delta[delta < 0]
    u[u.index[period-1]] = np.mean( u[:period] ) #first value is sum of avg gains
    u = u.drop(u.index[:(period-1)])
    d[d.index[period-1]] = np.mean( d[:period] ) #first value is sum of avg losses
    d = d.drop(d.index[:(period-1)])
    rs = pd.DataFrame.ewm(u, com=period-1, adjust=False).mean() / \
         pd.DataFrame.ewm(d, com=period-1, adjust=False).mean()
    output = 100 - 100 / (1 + rs)
    return output
```

Trying to access

```
data = pd.Series(closes)
print(data[0]) // no values getting only the float64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access values of a pandas series you can use

```
data = pd.Series(closes)
print(data.values[0])
```